# How to convert a PDF to a JSON/EXCEL/WORD file?

Tags: java, excel, pdf, ms-word, ocr

I need to get data from the pdf file with its header for further comparing with DB data

I tried to use the pdfbox , google vision ocr , itext, but all libraries gave me a row without structure and headers.

Example: Date\nNumber\nStatus\n12\12\2020\n442334\delivered

I will trying convert pdf to excel/word and get data from them, but for this realisation i need reading pdf and write data in excel/word

How can I get data with headers?

Comment: Pdfs do not necessarily contain information like "this is a table" or "this is a header". There only needs to be information like "here is this text" or "here is this line/rectangle/..." Anything beyond that usually can only be determined by heuristics,  educated guesswork. There are some services or software packages that have come pretty far with such heuristics. Check out e.g. tabula which is a project specialized on table data extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not found answer on my question.

I'm use this code for my task :

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExtractTextByArea {

    public String getTextFromCoordinate(String filepath,int x,int y,int width,int height) {
        String result = "";
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filepath))) {

            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
                stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
               // Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(260, 35, 70, 10);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
                stripper.addRegion("class1", rect);
                PDPage firstPage = document.getPage(0);
                stripper.extractRegions( firstPage );
               // System.out.println("Text in the area:" + rect);
                result = stripper.getTextForRegion("class1");

            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Date\nNumber\nStatus\n12/12/2020\n442334\ndelivered" looks structured enough to me. You could just split it at the "\n"s. That would require some knowledge of the table structure, though.

I've made good experience with Google Vision OCR. How are you calling it?

Comment: I use this code on java  https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf
I need data type : 
 Date 12/12/2020 
Number 442334
Status delivered 

or in JSON 

"Date" : "12/12/2020"
etc

Comment: The Java code there has this comment at the end : “Here we print the full text from the first page. The response contains more information: annotation/pages/blocks/paragraphs/words/symbols including confidence score and bounding boxes“

Have you checked if the response object contains the information you need?

Comment: Yes, i have checked it. I have json after OCR : "text":"Date\nNumber\nStatus\n12\12\2020\n442334\delivered" + other information doest not not interesting for me